# The meaning of should when used with suggest

Tags: modal-verbs

> It has been suggested that bright children should take their exams
> early.

I think "should" doesn't mean "ought to" in this sentence.

But if I want to infuse this meaning in the sentence how can I do you?

> It has been suggested that bright children should HAVE TO take their exams
> early.

> It has been suggested that bright children should SHOULD take their exams
> early.

Comment: What's wrong with using _ought to_?

Comment: What does :ought to: have to do with the question?

Comment: When you say 'infuse this meaning into the sentence', do you mean 'the meaning _ought to_?

Answer (score 1):

I think 'ought to' is a pretty good definition of 'should'. It doesn't alone imply that there is any compulsion to do something that you 'should', but it depends on the **context**. For example, children *should* go to school. There may be no compulsion to go, but there may be consequences for not doing so.

When you say "bright children *should* take their exams early" it sounds like a suggestion, and that the choice may be up to the children or their parents.

In your second example, which says the children "*should have to*", it is suggesting that there *should* be some compulsion, not that the compulsion already exists. For example, if education laws of a particular country dictate when a child takes an exam, saying they "should have to" take them earlier may suggest a *possible* change in the law. But as you are saying this 'should' happen, it doesn't mean that it will - that may be just your opinion.

Your last example doesn't make any sense - perhaps you have made an error?

Comment: I remember one american's take on it and they said that "I suggest that he should do it" means "I suggest that he should be the one who must do it." Have you heard such an opinion before?

Comment: @user1425 That's perfectly idiomatic. But all of these are just suggestions - the difference is what they are a suggestion of. Are you suggesting that children should choose to sit exams early, or are you suggesting that someone else should force them to? The example you just quoted has "must" in it, but it's only a suggestion that they 'should' be made to.

Comment: I am not suggesting anything. I am just trying to understand what the sentences mean. I am getting confused a bit. 1 It has been suggested that bright children should take their exams early. - I understand this sentence to mean that children should do nothing. They are not obliged to do anything. Should (in 1) doesn't mean "to be obliged. Am I correct?